# problems by installing package from github

Tags: r, github, installation, package, devtools

I am trying to install a package from GitHub, but everytime I get an error ( see below). I updated devtools but nothing changed. Does anyone has an idea to solve this problem?

```
> if(!require(FieldSpectroscopyDP)) install_github("tommasojulitta/FieldSpectroscopyDP") 
Lade nötiges Paket: FieldSpectroscopyDP
Downloading GitHub repo tommasojulitta/FieldSpectroscopyDP@master
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\dlenz\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSCOlR5\remotes2acc531b3f5\tommasojulitta-FieldSpectroscopyDP-181d481/DESCRIPTION' (607ms)
-  preparing 'FieldSpectroscopyDP': (408ms)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
   Warnung: C:/Users/dlenz/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpmYDhQj/Rbuild1245b5650d1/FieldSpectroscopyDP/man/FieldSpectroscopyDP-package.Rd:6: unexpected '}'
   Warnung: C:/Users/dlenz/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpmYDhQj/Rbuild1245b5650d1/FieldSpectroscopyDP/man/FieldSpectroscopyDP-package.Rd:8: unexpected '}'
   Warnung: C:/Users/dlenz/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpmYDhQj/Rbuild1245b5650d1/FieldSpectroscopyDP/man/FieldSpectroscopyDP-package.Rd:18: unexpected '}'
-  installing the package to process help pages (438ms)
-  saving partial Rd database (6.8s)
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
-  building 'FieldSpectroscopyDP_0.5.227.tar.gz'

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/dlenz/OneDrive/Dokumente/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'FieldSpectroscopyDP' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
Error : (konvertiert von Warnung) C:/Users/dlenz/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpmYDhQj/Rbuild1245b5650d1/FieldSpectroscopyDP/man/FieldSpectroscopyDP-package.Rd:17: All text must be in a section
ERROR: installing Rd objects failed for package 'FieldSpectroscopyDP'
* removing 'C:/Users/dlenz/OneDrive/Dokumente/R/win-library/3.6/FieldSpectroscopyDP'
Error: Failed to install 'FieldSpectroscopyDP' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/dlenz/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpSCOlR5/file2accdd5b6c/FieldSpectroscopyDP_0.5.227.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
In addition: Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  es gibt kein Paket namens ‘FieldSpectroscopyDP’
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in the .md file, see here: https://github.com/tommasojulitta/FieldSpectroscopyDP/blob/master/man/FieldSpectroscopyDP-package.Rd

But what you can do:

1. Clone the repository via `git clone https://github.com/tommasojulitta/FieldSpectroscopyDP`
2. Open the RStudio project
3. Build the package on your own via `STRG+SHIFT+B`(on Windows) or via the `build` panel in RStudio

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer and i should comment, but too low rep, unfortunately.

I ran into a similar problem once. The solution was to install Rtools (google it) and update R to newest version and run it as administrator.

This might work for you.

Cheers

Comment: Rtools is installed and R is updated but nothing changed. Still the same problem